# iterate loop at least 1000 times

Tags: java, loops, iteration

I have a while loop which exits when some condition met is true. i.e.,

```
boolean end = false;
while(!end){
    //Some operations based on random values
    //if statement to check my condition, and if it is met, then
end = true; //exits loop
}
```

Now since my program executes based on random numbers generated, sometimes the loop runs > 1000 times and some times < 1000 times(like 200, 300 etc). I want this code to iterate at least a 1000 times before checking the condition and exiting the loop. How do I do that?

Comment: Take one count variable outside of loop and increment within loop and check this count variable. When this variable meet to 1000 the break it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With an additional condition and a counter:

```
boolean end = false;
int count = 0;
while(!end){
  count++;
  //Some operations based on random values
  //if statement to check my condition, and if it is met, then
  if (count>1000){
    end = true; //exits loop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int numberOfIteration = 0;
while(!end){
  numberOfIteration++;
    //Some operations based on random values
    //if loop to check my condition, and if it is met, then
  if(numberOfIteration > 1000){
   end = true; //exits loop
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
boolean end = false;
int counter =0;


 while(!end){
    counter++;
        //Some operations based on random values
        //if statement to check my condition, and if it is met, then
    end = true; //exits loop
    if(counter<1000)
         continue;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is very simple,Divide your condition in to steps:

- Declare a counter and update that counter in every iteration.
- Check mycondition using if statement

  - if mycondition is true apply another if condition to check if the  counter has reached 1000.
        if both conditions become true,only then update your end variable

so your overall solution become:

```
boolean end = false;
int count = 0;
while(!end){
  count++;
  //Some operations based on random values

 if(mycondition){
    if (count>1000)
     end = true;
  } //exits loop
}
```